# Any idea by when the drill-down with charts feature will be available in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

We designed a lot of reports with drill-down chart in PowerBI designer last week. however, with the version they released on July 24th, they ripped off this feature.

Any one having any idea of by when they are going to get the drill-down feature back in Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is already available now. I have used them many times over. They have been available since december 2015. See documentation:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-drill-down-in-a-visualization/

Comment: December of what year? Any reference on that?

Comment: December 2015 - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-drill-down-in-a-visualization/

Answer (score 1):

We’re working to bring back the features like drill down. Best way to keep updated on features is to head over to [support.powerbi.com](https://support.powerbi.com/) and submit a suggestion; we’ll notify you when it’s in the product.

Comment: thanks for your reply and pointing to support.powerbi... However, my question is still not approved by the moderators there even after 24 hours... I suspect if there will be a reply!